# How do I create multiline headers in Laravel Excel?

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel 3.1 to export data to Excel.  My client wants to have multiple heading lines which include some metadata for the report such as report type and dates.  Below is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
Column A| Column B   | Column C
Type:   | Balances   |
Date:   | 01/01/2019 |
Account | Name       | Total
12345   | Johnson    | $10,000
54321   | Smith      | $25,000
```

I'm able to create column headings (Account, Name, and Total in my example) by using the `headings` array on my `Export` models but that falls short of the end goal.  How would I create something with the additional `Type` and `Date` rows?

Comment: You can create multiple header in the same way by adding the multiple lines of header elements. Detail is [here](https://tunda.work/en/questions/73?s=sta)